# Show message of how many records were deleted

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am using absolute database from Components Ace. Is it possible to know (display message) of how many records were deleted after running a delete query ?

Comment: +1 Why the downvote? This might a question of someone never having encountered RowsAffected or not being able to find it in the docs. I tried to Google the question different ways and that is not a 'first answer' search either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this value from the [`RowsAffected`](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/tabsquery_rowsaffected.htm) property after you execute your `DELETE` query. From the reference (emphasized by me):

> **Inspect RowsAffected to determine how many rows were updated or deleted** by the last query operation. If no rows were updated or
>   deleted, RowsAffected has a value of zero. RowsAffected will have a
>   value of -1 if the execution of the SQL statement could not be
>   executed due to an error condition. This latter situation would
>   typically follow the raising of an exception.

In a pseudo-code it might look like this:

```
...
ABSQuery1.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn = 1';
ABSQuery1.ExecSQL;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(ABSQuery1.RowsAffected) + ' row(s) were deleted.');
...
```